# How is the EMQ Web Dashboard user/password changed?

Tags: emq

I do not see any configuration or documentation on how to change the username/password for the emqtt.io Web Dashboard.  Does anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 5):

- Login to the emq broker web dashboard using default username as
  *admin* and password as *public* The web dashboard is running on the port 18083 by default so your url will be like http://localhost:18083
- Click on **Users** on the bottom left of the web dashboard page.
- Click on edit button on the right of the username for which you want
  change password for.
- A popup will be shown having an option to change
  user password.  Click on save and the password will be changed.

Hope this helps ! Thanks.

Comment: What version are you recommending for this flow to work?

Comment: The recommended Version is 2.3.9